# Spring Boot Caffeine Cache with Spring Expression Language

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, spring-el, caffeine-cache

I am using Spring boot with Caffeine Cache. My key for the cache is a Long and I need the key to be for eg : "1234-RULE" where 1234 is the Long object and -RULE is just a suffix. I tried the below to achieve this :

```
private final static String RULE_KEY = "#rule.id.concat('-RULE')";

@Cacheable(value = CacheConfig.RULE_OFFSET, key = RULE_KEY)
public BigDecimal getRuleOffset(final Rule rule) {

  // some code to fetch the value and return it

}
```

While debugging, I get the error :

```
Error occurred while performing the request. Message: EL1004E: Method call: Method concat(java.lang.String) cannot be found on type java.lang.Long
```

My rule.id is Long and it seems the expression that I'm using to concat the id and the suffix is incorrect. Can you please tell me how to concat a long and string here for my use case.

Comment: Have you tried simply `#rule.id + '-RULE'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for EL can be a bit odd at times, but you can just use `+` as a concatenation operator here:

```
#rule.id + '-RULE'
```